# Why is my NSArray returning an inaccurate count with arrayWithObjects of UIImages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm completely lost with this. I'm receiving a `nil` error so I tried to print out the count of my `NSArray`. I have 20 `UIImages` initialized in the array, which should return a count of 20, but it returns a count of 17.

```
images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"4"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"5"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"6"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"7"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"8"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"9"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"10"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"11"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"12"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"13"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"14"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"15"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"16"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"17"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"18"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"19"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"20"], nil ];
```

When I do a `[images count]`, it returns 17.

Why is this? Why does it stop counting at 17? Thanks

Comment: What is `[UIImage imageNamed:@"18"]`? I bet it's nil.

Comment: As Kurt hints, you don't actually have an image named `18.png` (or one of its size variants) in your app bundle.

Comment: wow, I was too quick to check the naming of my 18th image, I apologize for the rush in judgement, please provide the answer and I will accept it kurt :)

Answer (score -2):

Your app would not be having any image named 18,19 and 20 and therefore when you add object to array as [UIImage imageNamed:@"18"], it takes nil object.